# getting RC=notconnected error while trying to scan a barcode through program on windows mobile on honeywell scanphone6000

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-5.0, honeywell

We have developed a windows mobile 6.5 application that scans a barcode on Honeywell Scanphone 6000. We have used the sample code that comes with Honeywell Scanphone as power tools. Now, we have to start scanwedge application in the background in order to scan a barcode. Until this it was ok but when it is scanning the barcode it throws an error message like following:

"Not connected. Connect to engine first. RC=notconnected" The message appears and then if I click ok it goes back to my application and starts the barcode.

The client now wants the error message to be removed but I am clueless at this point as to how to remove it as I have no idea what this corresponds to. I have searched a lot in the internet but could not find any more than the fact that RC= remote control.

Have anyone faced such a problem before? Please let me know.

Comment: Is the message sent from your application? can't you catch the exception showing this message in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - The issue is the driver DLLs for the decoder fail to load.  Take the battery off, put it back on, let it boot - should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Just did Power Off, then Power On. Without taking the battery off needing a small hex-star screwer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - The actual problem is discribed by Honeywell.
If the decode assembly is blocked from the Scanwedge your tool will throw this error.

Link to the official description:
[Honeywell description](http://hsm.force.com/publickb/articles/HSM_Article/Why-does-the-application-display-the-following-error-message-RC-Not-Connected)